# Проверка пиксель в пиксель на мобильном приложении

Tags: html

Если нужно например проверит верстку пиксель в пиксель в браузере то это легко.Для браузеров есть программы для наложения ПДФ на верстку.

А как быть если мне нужно проверить пиксель в пиксель в 
мобильном приложении (проверять буду на телефоне с ОС Андроид) ?

Кто то знает программу для проверки пиксель в пиксель верстки на мобильном телефоне ?

Comment: Пиксель-в-пиксель на телефонах (особенно на андроидах) вы не получите никогда, потому что у каждого устройства своя собственная плотность пикселей и каждый браузер будет рисовать всё по-разному. Ну а вообще, наверно, ничто вам не мешает сделать скриншот и наложить его на ПДФ (или наоборот) в любом графическом редакторе

Comment: да пожалуй наложу на ПК изображение с мобильного